# json_decode - Force array keys to be string

Tags: php, json, associative-array

Take a look at the following code:

```
$a = json_decode('{"0":"xy"}', true);
```

This will return an associative array like `[0 => "xy"]`.

Is there a way **not** to automatically convert the keys to numbers? The result I'd like to have would be the array `["0" => "xy"]` with strings as keys exclusively.

Comment: And why do you want it to be like that? What is wrong with that?

Comment: This is an attribute of a Laravel Eloquent model. When the model is converted to JSON (e.g. when returned by the API) `[0 => "xy"]` is converted to `["xy"]` and not the correct `{"0":"xy"}`.

Comment: You can still get the keys

Comment: Then take this example: `{"0":"xy","2":"xy"}`. It will be converted to `[0 => "xy", 2 => "xy"]`. This in turn will be encoded to the original JSON when returned by the API. I want *both* examples (this and the one in my question) to behave the same.

Answer (score 3):

First decode it as an object (without `true` parameter) and then typecast it as array:

```
$a = (array) json_decode('{"0":"xy"}');
var_dump($a);
```

Ouput:

```
array (size=1)
  '0' => string 'xy' (length=2)
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Unfortunately I need this to be recursive so I hoped to find a more "native" method that doesn't require me to traverse the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you would want numerical array keys to be strings. It can make life harder when trying to search through an array by key or rekey the array.

However, if you really want your keys to be strings this should help

```
$array = json_decode('{"0":"xy"}', true);
foreach($array as $key => $value) { 
   $newArray[(string) $key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: `strval` or `"$key"` should work, too. But here, too, I would need to recursively traverse the array to convert all keys manually. I hoped for a more "native" method like a flag for `json_decode` or something.

Comment: There isnt a native method, not to my knowledge. Why do you need your keys as strings? Seems a bit odd since they are numerical values...What do you gain from such an exercise?

Comment: The important part is that it can be arbitrary numerical values (in arbitrary order). But never mind, I've now decided to change the underlying datastructure rather than to struggle with `json_decode`.